# How to speed up while loop with PyAutoGui?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am making a very simple spambot for Discord just for pranking my friends. But the while True: command is very slow. Is there a faster alternative?

```py
import PIL
import pyautogui, time
time.sleep(5)
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
while True:
    pyautogui.hotkey("command", "v")
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    
if (pyautogui.locateOnScreen("av.png")):
    (pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("av.png")))
```

Comment: If `while true` is genuinely too slow, you really can't use Python for this. Probably the problem is with the speed of whatever you are running inside the loop, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=failsafe#fail-safes):

> Like the enchanted brooms from the Sorcerer’s Apprentice programmed to keep filling (and then overfilling) the bath with water, a bug in your program could make it go out of control. It’s hard to use the mouse to close a program if the mouse cursor is moving around on its own.

> As a safety feature, a fail-safe feature is enabled by default. When a PyAutoGUI function is called, if the mouse is in any of the four corners of the primary monitor, they will raise a pyautogui.FailSafeException. There is a one-tenth second delay after calling every PyAutoGUI functions to give the user time to slam the mouse into a corner to trigger the fail safe.

> You can disable this failsafe by setting pyautogui.FAILSAFE = False. I HIGHLY RECOMMEND YOU DO NOT DISABLE THE FAILSAFE.

> The tenth-second delay is set by the pyautogui.PAUSE setting, which is 0.1 by default. You can change this value. There is also a pyautogui.DARWIN_CATCH_UP_TIME setting which adds an additional delay on macOS after keyboard and mouse events, since the operating system appears to need a delay after PyAutoGUI issues these events. It is set to 0.01 by default, adding an additional hundredth-second delay.

Therefore, if you want to "speed up" your loop, you can reduce the `pyautogui.PAUSE` value. However, keep in mind, this will prevent you from having time to activate the failsafe if you need it.